# $\frac{X}{k+X}$ has low variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X$ is a random variable. I was wondering if it's reasonable to say that $\operatorname{var}(\frac{X}{k+X})\approx0$ where $k$ is a constant. Intuitively, it feels like this statement is true. Is this in general true or are there any specific distributions that this might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\frac{X}{k+X} = 1-\frac{k}{k+X}$ so $\operatorname{Var}(\frac{X}{k+X}) = k^2\operatorname{Var}(\frac{1}{k+X})$. There are situations where $\frac{1}{k+X}$ might have large variance, such as if $X$ takes values near $-k$. However if $X$ avoids the interval $[-k-\epsilon, -k+\epsilon]$, then I think $\frac{1}{k+X}$ will take values in the interval $[-1/\epsilon, 1/\epsilon]$. You can then use [Popoviciu's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances) to bound the variance of $\frac{1}{k+X}$.

Comment: I changed $k^2\text{Var}(\frac{1}{k+X})$ to $k^2\operatorname{Var}(\frac{1}{k+X}),$ fixing the conspicuous lack of proper spacing. The use of `\operatorname{}` does not merely add horizontal space; rather it makes the spacing depend on the context. (I wonder how some people who use LaTeX habitually for years continue to miss things like this.)

Comment: Brilliant!!!!! Thank you !

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the edit. I use `\operatorname` inside custom-defined macros (e.g., defining a macro named `\Var` using `\operatorname{Var}`) when writing papers in actual Latex, but don't really bother using `\operatorname` in MathJax out of laziness. I would disagree with the spacing difference being "conspicuous"; even in your comment I did not notice the difference in the side-by-side comparison until after several seconds of looking for it.